# Django 1.6b gis import error

Tags: django, django-models, gis

I'm using django 1.6b and python 3.3 and I get this import error,

```
./manage.py runserver
Validating models...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x104ae4d40>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/boxen/pyenv/versions/side-project/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 93, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/boxen/pyenv/versions/side-project/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 97, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/opt/boxen/pyenv/versions/side-project/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 308, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/opt/boxen/pyenv/versions/side-project/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 34, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "/opt/boxen/pyenv/versions/side-project/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 196, in get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "/opt/boxen/pyenv/version/side-project/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 78, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name)
  File "/opt/boxen/pyenv/versions/side-project/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 99, in load_app
    models = import_module('.models', app_name)
  File "/opt/boxen/pyenv/versions/side-project/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/moi/Projects/sos/dealerships/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.db import models # as geomodels
  File "/opt/boxen/pyenv/versions/side-project/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.db.models.manager import GeoManager
  File "/opt/boxen/pyenv/versions/side-project/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/manager.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.db.models.query import GeoQuerySet
  File "/opt/boxen/pyenv/versions/side-project/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/query.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.db.models.fields import get_srid_info, PointField, LineStringField
  File "/opt/boxen/pyenv/versions/side-project/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/fields.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis import forms
  File "/opt/boxen/pyenv/versions/side-project/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/forms/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .fields import (GeometryField, GeometryCollectionField, PointField,
  File "/opt/boxen/pyenv/versions/side-project/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/forms/fields.py", line 11, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSException, GEOSGeometry, fromstr
ImportError: cannot import name GEOSException
```

This is the only code I have in place for gis,

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models as geomodels
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
from django.contrib.localflavor.us.models import USStateField

class UsLocation(geomodels.Model):
    address_1 = geomodels.CharField(_("address"), max_length=128)
    address_2 = geomodels.CharField(_("address cont'd"), max_length=128, blank=True)

    city = geomodels.CharField(_("city"), max_length=64, default="Kansas City")
    state = USStateField(_("state"), default="KO")
    zip_code = geomodels.CharField(_("zip code"), max_length=5, default="16874")
```

For now I'm going to not use the gis helpers for my address model but I'm not sure what's causing this import exception. I checked the django 1.5/1.6 releases and they have the same lines. I wonder if it has something to do with me using 1.6b w/ python 3.3.2 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you have installed the [Geospatial libraries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/gis/install/geolibs/). I have tested Python 3.3.2 and Django 1.6 beta 2 in a virtual env. The import from `contrib.gis` works fine.

```
>>> import django
>>> django.VERSION
(1, 6, 0, 'beta', 2)
>>> from django.contrib.gis.db import models as geomodels
```

Note that `contrib.localflavor` [has been removed from Django 1.6](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/localflavor/#deprecation-policy).

```
>>> from django.contrib.localflavor.us.models import USStateField
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'django.contrib.localflavor'
```

You can install the `django-localflavor` package with:

```
pip install django-localflavor
```

then change your import to:

```
from localflavor.us.models import USStateField
```

Comment: In ubuntu , execute this ( sudo apt-get install binutils libproj-dev gdal-bin) retry

Answer (score 1):

I have just faced the same problem. Unfortunately, `ImportError: cannot import name GEOSException` is not the best error message when Django cannot find GEOS library.

I have Django 1.6.1 final and Python 3.3 too. OS is Windows 7 64-bit. Python, GEOS are x86-64 too.

As recommended at Django docs, the line:

```
GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = r'C:\Program Files\OSGeo4W64\bin\geos_c.dll'
```

in my Django project settings solved this issue.